# How to make Django template recognize load tag upon inheriting from base template

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have the following **base.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<html>
   <title>COOL| {% block title %} Sometitle {% endblock %}</title>
<body>

   <!--- BEGIN INSERT CONTENT FOR OTHER PAGE  HERE-->
   {% block 'body' %}
   {% endblock %}
```

And I have **somefile.html** which are wrapped by the above.

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %} Contact {% endblock %}
{% block 'body' %}

 <h1> <a href="{%static "files/somefile.csv" %}">CSV</a> </h1>

{% endblock %}
```

The message I get is this:

```
Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'
```

I expect `somefile.html` will inherit `{% load static from staticfiles %}` from `base.html`. But it doesn't. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

You should load tags in each template.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I thought Django use [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) concept?

Comment: @pdubois Well, that's a question to the Django core team:)

Comment: @pdubois don't confuse DRY with sanity and maintainability, a large project may have multiple custom tags and not all of them neet to be processed in every template.