# Django: The static tag not loading on extended html when linking an image but works for CSS style sheet?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a layout.html file as follows:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="{% static 'app/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and a extended.html as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <h1>Extended</h1>
        <img src="{% static 'app/images/image.svg' %}" alt="image">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I load the exnteded.html I get the follwoing error:

`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 13: 'static', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

I have tested a few scenarios out:

1. If I remove the `<img src="{% static 'app/images/image.svg' %}" alt="image">` from the extended.html the CSS style sheet loads perfectly.
2. If I add `{% load static %}` to the extended.html the image and CSS style sheet both load.

I have had a look at the Django docs and have ensured that the settings.py file does have django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS and STATIC_URL = "static/".

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try adding it inside your {% block body %} tag maybe?

Comment: What's wrong with the scenario 2. that you tested where both CSS and image load?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Sure that works but I don't want to have to repeat on multiple extended html files. From my understanding that loading the static file once should work?

Comment: @nlewis99 still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Where did you see that it should work like that? This question is 8 years old, but indicates that it doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119385/how-to-make-django-template-recognize-load-tag-upon-inheriting-from-base-templat

Answer (score 0):

You don't define `app name` in `load static`.

You have just try to remove app name in your load static, Like,

Your `code`:

```
<link href="{% static 'app/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Try `My Answer`:

```
<link href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And also remove `app` name in load images,

Your `code`:

```
<img src="{% static 'app/images/image.svg' %}" alt="image">
```

Try `My Answer`:

```
<img src="{% static '/images/image.svg' %}" alt="image">
```